# Why is my powerup not showing up in my LOVE2D game?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm currently doing a Pong Remake called PlayBall, a colorful version with powerups, modes and new additions. I'm now in Alpha 2.0 (Powerup Concept) and I want to make my 1st powerup called AddBall.

What this powerup does is that when the ball collides with it, a new ball spawns in.

I set up the code in `AddBall.lua`:

```
AddBall = Class{}

local spawner = math.random(10, 20)

function AddBall:init(x, y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 8
    self.height = 8
    
    self.timer = 0
    
    self.inPlay = false
end

function AddBall:collides(ball)
    -- first, check to see if the left edge of either is farther to the right
    -- than the right edge of the other
    if self.x > ball.x + ball.width or ball.x > self.x + self.width then
        return false
    end

    -- then check to see if the bottom edge of either is higher than the top
    -- edge of the other
    if self.y > ball.y + ball.height or ball.y > self.y + self.height then
        return false
    end 

    -- if the above aren't true, they're overlapping
    return true
end

function AddBall:update(dt)
    self.timer = self.timer + dt
    
    if self.timer > spawner then
        self.inPlay = true
    end
    
    if self.inPlay then
        self:render()
    end
end

function AddBall:render()
    love.graphics.draw(textures['powerups'], frames['powerups'][1], self.x, self.y)
end

function AddBall:reset()
    self.timer = 0
    self.inPlay = false
    spawner = math.random(10, 20)
end
```

This is the best I made. Then I assigned a big bunch of stuff in `main.lua` to load the powerups and 2nd ball:

```
--[[
    Called just once at the beginning of the game; used to set up
    game objects, variables, etc. and prepare the game world.
]]
function love.load()
    -- set love's default filter to "nearest-neighbor", which essentially
    -- means there will be no filtering of pixels (blurriness), which is
    -- important for a nice crisp, 2D look
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')

    -- set the title of our application window
    love.window.setTitle('PlayBall')

    -- seed the RNG so that calls to random are always random
    math.randomseed(os.time())

    -- initialize our nice-looking retro text fonts
    smallFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 8)
    largeFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 16)
    scoreFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 32)
    love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)

    -- set up our sound effects; later, we can just index this table and
    -- call each entry's `play` method
    sounds = {
        ['paddle_hit'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/paddle_hit.wav', 'static'),
        ['score'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/score.wav', 'static'),
        ['wall_hit'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/wall_hit.wav', 'static')
    }
    
    textures = {
        ['powerups'] = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/powerups.png')
    }
    
    frames = {
        ['powerups'] = GenerateQuadsPowerups(textures['powerups'])
    }
    
    -- initialize our virtual resolution, which will be rendered within our
    -- actual window no matter its dimensions
    push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, {
        fullscreen = false,
        resizable = true,
        vsync = true
    })

    -- initialize our player paddles; make them global so that they can be
    -- detected by other functions and modules
    player1 = Paddle(10, 30, 5, 20)
    player2 = Paddle(VIRTUAL_WIDTH - 10, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 30, 5, 20)

    -- place a ball in the middle of the screen
    ball1 = Ball(VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - 2, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 2, 4, 4, 1)
    ball2 = Ball(ball1.x, ball1.y, 4, 4, 2)
    
    powerup1 = AddBall(math.random(20, VIRTUAL_WIDTH - 20), math.random(0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 8))

    -- set up in play to ensure it is in game
    ball1.inPlay = true

    -- initialize score variables
    player1Score = 0
    player2Score = 0

    -- either going to be 1 or 2; whomever is scored on gets to serve the
    -- following turn
    servingPlayer = 1

    -- player who won the game; not set to a proper value until we reach
    -- that state in the game
    winningPlayer = 0

    -- the state of our game; can be any of the following:
    -- 1. 'start' (the beginning of the game, before first serve)
    -- 2. 'serve' (waiting on a key press to serve the ball)
    -- 3. 'play' (the ball is in play, bouncing between paddles)
    -- 4. 'done' (the game is over, with a victor, ready for restart)
    gameState = 'start'
end
```

Then the game updates:

```
--[[
    Called every frame, passing in `dt` since the last frame. `dt`
    is short for `deltaTime` and is measured in seconds. Multiplying
    this by any changes we wish to make in our game will allow our
    game to perform consistently across all hardware; otherwise, any
    changes we make will be applied as fast as possible and will vary
    across system hardware.
]]
function love.update(dt)
    if gameState == 'serve' then
        -- before switching to play, initialize ball's velocity based
        -- on player who last scored
        ball1.dy = math.random(-50, 50)
        if servingPlayer == 1 then
            ball1.dx = math.random(140, 200)
        else
            ball1.dx = -math.random(140, 200)
        end
    elseif gameState == 'play' then
        -- detect ball collision with paddles, reversing dx if true and
        -- slightly increasing it, then altering the dy based on the position
        -- at which it collided, then playing a sound effect
        if ball1:collides(player1) then
            ball1.dx = -ball1.dx * 1.03
            ball1.x = player1.x + 5

            -- keep velocity going in the same direction, but randomize it
            if ball1.dy < 0 then
                ball1.dy = -math.random(10, 150)
            else
                ball1.dy = math.random(10, 150)
            end

            sounds['paddle_hit']:play()
        end
        if ball1:collides(player2) then
            ball1.dx = -ball1.dx * 1.03
            ball1.x = player2.x - 4

            -- keep velocity going in the same direction, but randomize it
            if ball1.dy < 0 then
                ball1.dy = -math.random(10, 150)
            else
                ball1.dy = math.random(10, 150)
            end

            sounds['paddle_hit']:play()
        end
        if ball2:collides(player1) then
            ball2.dx = -ball2.dx * 1.03
            ball2.x = player1.x + 5

            -- keep velocity going in the same direction, but randomize it
            if ball2.dy < 0 then
                ball2.dy = -math.random(10, 150)
            else
                ball2.dy = math.random(10, 150)
            end

            sounds['paddle_hit']:play()
        end
        if ball2:collides(player2) then
            ball2.dx = -ball2.dx * 1.03
            ball2.x = player2.x - 4

            -- keep velocity going in the same direction, but randomize it
            if ball2.dy < 0 then
                ball2.dy = -math.random(10, 150)
            else
                ball2.dy = math.random(10, 150)
            end

            sounds['paddle_hit']:play()
        end

        -- detect upper and lower screen boundary collision, playing a sound
        -- effect and reversing dy if true
        if ball1.y <= 0 then
            ball1.y = 0
            ball1.dy = -ball1.dy
            sounds['wall_hit']:play()
        end

        -- -4 to account for the ball's size
        if ball1.y >= VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 4 then
            ball1.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 4
            ball1.dy = -ball1.dy
            sounds['wall_hit']:play()
        end
        
        -- detect upper and lower screen boundary collision, playing a sound
        -- effect and reversing dy if true
        if ball2.y <= 0 then
            ball2.y = 0
            ball2.dy = -ball2.dy
            sounds['wall_hit']:play()
        end

        -- -4 to account for the ball's size
        if ball2.y >= VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 4 then
            ball2.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 4
            ball2.dy = -ball2.dy
            sounds['wall_hit']:play()
        end

        -- if we reach the left edge of the screen, go back to serve
        -- and update the score and serving player
        if ball1.x < 0 then
            servingPlayer = 1
            player2Score = player2Score + 1
            sounds['score']:play()

            -- if we've reached a score of 10, the game is over; set the
            -- state to done so we can show the victory message
            if player2Score == 10 then
                winningPlayer = 2
                gameState = 'done'
            else
                gameState = 'serve'
                -- places the ball in the middle of the screen, no velocity
                ball1:reset()
            end
        end

        -- if we reach the right edge of the screen, go back to serve
        -- and update the score and serving player
        if ball1.x > VIRTUAL_WIDTH then
            servingPlayer = 2
            player1Score = player1Score + 1
            sounds['score']:play()

            -- if we've reached a score of 10, the game is over; set the
            -- state to done so we can show the victory message
            if player1Score == 10 then
                winningPlayer = 1
                gameState = 'done'
            else
                gameState = 'serve'
                -- places the ball in the middle of the screen, no velocity
                ball1:reset()
            end
        end
        
        -- check if ball powerup is added
        if powerup1:collides(ball1) then
            ball2.inPlay = true
            ball2:update(dt)
            powerup1:reset()
        end
        
        -- ball 2 is resetted when it hits the edge
        if ball2.x < 0 or ball2.x > VIRTUAL_WIDTH then
            ball2.inPlay = false
        end
    end

    --
    -- paddles can move no matter what state we're in
    --
    -- player 1
    if love.keyboard.isDown('w') then
        player1.dy = -PADDLE_SPEED
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('s') then
        player1.dy = PADDLE_SPEED
    else
        player1.dy = 0
    end

    -- player 2
    if aiMode == true then
        player2.y = ball1.y
    elseif aiMode == false then
        if love.keyboard.isDown('up') then
            player2.dy = -PADDLE_SPEED
        elseif love.keyboard.isDown('down') then
            player2.dy = PADDLE_SPEED
        else
            player2.dy = 0
        end
    end

    -- update our ball based on its DX and DY only if we're in play state;
    -- scale the velocity by dt so movement is framerate-independent
    if gameState == 'play' then
        ball1:update(dt)
    end

    player1:update(dt)
    player2:update(dt)
    powerup1:update(dt)
end
```

My problem is that the powerup won't spawn in, making the powerup concept incomplete. I'm not sure if I caused a problem with the rendering, or the timing didn't go well.

My guess is that I made problems with `Ball.lua`:

```
Ball = Class{}

function Ball:init(x, y, width, height, num)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.count = num

    -- these variables are for keeping track of our velocity on both the
    -- X and Y axis, since the ball can move in two dimensions
    self.dy = 0
    self.dx = 0
    
    self.inPlay = false
end

--[[
    Expects a paddle as an argument and returns true or false, depending
    on whether their rectangles overlap.
]]
function Ball:collides(paddle)
    -- first, check to see if the left edge of either is farther to the right
    -- than the right edge of the other
    if self.x > paddle.x + paddle.width or paddle.x > self.x + self.width then
        return false
    end

    -- then check to see if the bottom edge of either is higher than the top
    -- edge of the other
    if self.y > paddle.y + paddle.height or paddle.y > self.y + self.height then
        return false
    end 

    -- if the above aren't true, they're overlapping
    return true
end

--[[
    Places the ball in the middle of the screen, with no movement.
]]
function Ball:reset()
    self.x = VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - 2
    self.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 2
    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0
end

function Ball:update(dt)
    self.x = self.x + self.dx * dt
    self.y = self.y + self.dy * dt
end

function Ball:render()
    if self.inPlay then
        love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)
        love.graphics.setColor(0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf(tostring(self.count), 2, self.y - 8, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.rectangle('fill', self.x + 2, self.y + 2, self.width, self.height)
        love.graphics.setColor(255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
        love.graphics.printf(tostring(self.count), 0, self.y - 10, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.rectangle('fill', self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    end
end
```

Or in `AddBall.lua`, but my powerup won't spawn. Can you tell me why?

I will post the stuff in GitHub if you want to look closer, my AddBall powerup is the green cross.

Comment: please don't expect us to debug this huge load of code. narrow your problem down by creating a simple minimal example code for all the bricks of your code. if you are unsure if the problem is caused by rendering or timing test both separately.

Comment: @Piglet Well, thanks for trying to help. At least you gave me clues on the context of the problem. So thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that your powerup didn't show up. It's probably because you didn't call `powerup1:render()` in `love.draw` for that reasoning. Try updating the concept of spawning the powerup and the ball, since you need to render it somehow.

Try it like this:

```
if powerup1.inPlay then
    powerup1:render()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its cause you only update ball2 if the powerup collides with ball1. Since you render the ball in the update method, you'll only be able to see it if it updates(which it doesnt)

I suggest that you rather do this:

```
if ball2.inPlay then
     ball2:update(dt)
end
```